# Excel VBA - Triple Nested Loop to tie column keys together

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to set up a nested loop that can tie together different columns only when the column in question has data.

What I have is a table like this:

```
|Aname       |aterm    |amod     |
|            |         |         |
|Smith, Bob  |         |         |
|            |         |         |
|            |         |         |
|            | 2/6/2017|         |
|            |         |         |
|            |         |Module 1 |
|            |         |         |
|Smith, John |         |         |
|            |         |         |
|            |         |         |
|            |5/12/2017|         |
|            |         |Module 6 |
|            |         |         |
|            |         |Module 4 |
|            |         |         |
|            |6/12/2017|         |
|            |         |         |
|            |         |Module 10|
|            |         |Module 5 |
```

What I am trying to do is tie the columns together like so:

```
|aname       |aterm      |amod       |
|Smith, Bob  | 02/6/2017 | Module 1  |
|Smith, John | 5/12/2014 | Module 6  |
|Smith, John | 5/12/2014 | Module 4  |
|Smith, John | 6/12/2014 | Module 10 |
|Smith, John | 6/12/2014 | Module 5  |
```

Below is the code I put together to pull this off. Unfortunately, the printing is picking up the aname dozens of time, the aterm intermittently, and the amod not at all.

```
Sub looper()

Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range

aname = ""
aterm = ""
amod = ""

Set listenroll = [table1[aname]]
Set atermrange = [table1[aterm]]
Set amodrange = [table1[amod]]

For Each rng In listenroll
    If IsEmpty(rng) = False Then
        Set aname = rng
        For Each rng2 In atermrange
            If IsEmpty(rng2) = False Then
                Set aterm = rng2
                For Each rng3 In amodrange
                    If IsEmpty(rng3) = False Then
                        Set amodrange = rng3
                        Range("I1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = aname
                        Range("J1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = aterm
                        Range("K1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = amod
                    End If
                Next rng3
            End If
        Next rng2
    End If
Next rng
```

Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Comment: Another route would be to fill in the empty cells with the appropriate duplicates, then use remove duplicates.  May be quicker than 3 loops.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one loop:

```
Sub looper()

    Dim aname As String
    'Dim aterm As String
    Dim aterm As Date
    Dim amod As String

    aname = ""
    'aterm = ""
    aterm = 0
    amod = ""

    Set listenroll = [table1[aname]]
    Set atermrange = [table1[aterm]]
    Set amodrange = [table1[amod]]

    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 to amodrange.Rows.Count
        'Record value of AName whenever it changes
        If Trim(listenroll(r, 1).Value) <> vbNullString Then
            aname = Trim(listenroll(r, 1).Value)
        End If
        'Record value of ATerm whenever it changes
        If Trim(atermrange(r, 1).Value) <> vbNullString Then
            'aterm = Trim(atermrange(r, 1).Value)
            aterm = CDate(atermrange(r, 1).Value)
        End If
        'Write output each time there is something in amod
        If Trim(amodrange(r, 1).Value) <> vbNullString Then
            amod = Trim(amodrange(r, 1).Value)
            Range("I1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = aname
            Range("J1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = aterm
            Range("K1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = amod
        End If
    Next
```

Note: I'm not sure how to modify aterm to match your question's example, but I'm hoping that's just a typo in the example.

---

And, FWIW, you have one major error in your existing code at the point where you say `Set amodrange = rng3`.  I'm not sure whether that is the **only** error.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I got a few matches, but the date range didn't carry to multiple modules in the same term, plus I got a lot of rows with the name but no other data.

Comment: @Jwok Sorry - you had used `IsEmpty` in your code, so I used it too, but that doesn't appear to work on table data - hopefully fixed now.  Also, I changed `aterm` to be a `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative solution for you. This is basically the same thing with YowE3K's code, however there is one more `for` loop and one less `if` statement. This is because, instead of using table names I used column A B C assuming your table is there, and also stored the values in an array.

Try this:

```
Sub looper()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, LastCell As Long
Dim arr() As String
ReDim arr(2)
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastCell = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = 2 To LastCell
        For j = 1 To 3
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, j)) Then
                arr(j - 1) = .Cells(i, j)
                If j = 3 Then
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = arr(0)
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = arr(1)
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = arr(2)
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work either. There were no rows in which data from all three columns was present. Also, the loop kept going well past the range I wanted to use.